# Is this possible to use two \label for same equation

Tags: equations, labels

Is this possible to use different `label`s for same equation number, I've tried with the below code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\label{test}
a+b=c\label{trial}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

but I got error, please advise...

Comment: As far as I know, the result is indeed correct. Because, you cannot use multiple lables for one equation.

Comment: Only one label is possible

Answer (score 4):

In simple cases, such as `\begin{equation}` you can have any number of `\label` (although there is no real need ever to do so) however in alignments then the code has to make sure that the `\label` works in any cell even though the left and right sides of the equation are really separate groups, so it drops multiple labels with a warning. There would be no real advantage to allowing it as `\ref{test}` would always be the same as `\ref{trial}`

Comment: As per your suggestion, I've changed align to equation, but still the same problem exists, please advise...

Comment: @MadyYuvi no my suggestion was to just have one `\label` why would you ever need two?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your words...

Comment: Well for a theorem because you wrote a whole book referencing two different theorems and then merged them into a single theorem.  I mean you can search and replace but then you lose some info in case you change your mind.

Comment: @PeterGerdes there are no problems having multiple `\label` for theorems, the issue is specific to alignments.